# How to add a number in a string to a number?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that get the actual brightness and decrease the string number by 0.1. I've tried numerous syntax but since I'm very new to bash this doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh

actualBrightness=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' ')

echo ${actualBrightness} # 0.5 for ex

if [[ $actualBrightness < 1 ]]
  then
  newBrightness=$(($actualBrightness-0.1))
  echo $newBrightness # must be 0.4
fi
```

Comment: Please add example input

Comment: Bash cannot do floating point arithmetic. You need to use awk or bc for example

Comment: This could easily break, as you're using `#!/bin/sh` and `[[ ]]`, but `[[ ]]` is a bash feature.

Comment: BTW, `[[ $actualBrightness < 1 ]]` is doing a string comparison. Even for integers, you want to use actual integer math -- as a string, for instance, `20` is greater than `100`, since comparison is character-by-character left-to-right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
$ echo "$b"
0.5
```

The `0.5` only has meaning to Bash as a string. You need to use `bc` or `awk` to interpret that as a floating point value change or change its value:

```
$ echo "$b-.1" | bc
.4
```

Bash does not do floating point math -- only integer math and string manipulation.

So to change the value of `b` you would do:

```
$ b=$(echo "$b-.1" | bc)
$ echo "$b"
.4
```

You can also use `bc` for testing:

```
$ echo "0.55 > 7" | bc
0
$ echo "55.2 > 7" | bc
1
```

1 is 'true' and then use that in your Bash `[[ test ]]` like so:

```
[[ $(echo "5 > 1" | bc) -eq 1 ]] # sets $? to 0 for true or 1 for false
                                 # BACKWARDS from bc's exit code
```

Or, single statement:

```
$ [[ $(echo "5 > 1" | bc) -eq "1" ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
true
$ [[ $(echo ".5 > 1" | bc) -eq "1" ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
false
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot !

Comment: Make sure you are actually using `bash` by having `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang -- NOT `#!/bin/sh` or the `[[ test ]]` won't work.

Comment: Yes I've made the modification, learn something, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to facilitate the floating-point arithmetic:

```
actualBrightness='0.5'
awk '{if ($1 < 1) { new=($1 - 0.1); printf new; }}' <<<"$actualBrightness"
# output: 0.4
```

### Explanation:

Awk operates on fields separated by a field-separator, which defaults to whitespace; the above statement checks to see:

1. Is the first field less than 1
2. Yes? Then set the variable `new` to `($1 - 0.1)` and print `new` to `STDOUT`
3. No? Then do nothing.